# Networkx is unable to find some packages (version 1.10)

Tags: python-2.7, networkx

I am using networkx for computation of `min_maximal_matching`, It gave the following error, I did a `pip install networkx --upgrade`, and on `version 1.10`

```
    >>> nx.min_maximal_matching
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'min_maximal_matching'
    >>> nx.__version__
    '1.10'
```

Just to do a sanity check, I tried with another method from the same group of function, ([approximation packages](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.approximation.html)), and it worked,

```
    >>> nx.node_connectivity
    <function node_connectivity at 0x10b517410>
```

Thanks! 
PS: I am using `python 2.7.8`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is not exposed in the `netxwork` namespace, but if you import `networkx.algorithms.approximation`, then you'll find it there:

```
In [311]: import networkx.algorithms.approximation as naa

In [312]: naa.min_maximal_matching
Out[319]: <function networkx.algorithms.approximation.matching.min_maximal_matching>
```

I found this by following [the link you provided](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.approximation.html) to the [min_maximal_matching doc page](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.matching.min_maximal_matching.html#networkx.algorithms.approximation.matching.min_maximal_matching) to the [source code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/approximation/matching.html#min_maximal_matching).

The source code makes it clear where the function is defined: `networkx.algorithms.approximation.matching`.

The [`networkx/algorithms/approximation/__init__.py`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/algorithms/approximation/__init__.py) file imports everything in the `networkx.algorithms.approximation.matching` namespace into the `networkx.algorthims.approximation` namespace:

```
from networkx.algorithms.approximation.matching import *
```

and this is why you can stop after importing

```
import networkx.algorithms.approximation as naa
```

instead of having to drill down even farther, as in

```
In [307]: import networkx.algorithms.approximation.matching as naam

In [308]: naam.min_maximal_matching
Out[310]: <function networkx.algorithms.approximation.matching.min_maximal_matching>
```

although, as you can see, that also works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I don't have enough rep to up vote you.

Comment: Does that mean if there is a `__init__.py` in algorithms package then they would be readily available ?

Comment: Yes, indeed! But as you can see, [`networkx/algorithms/__init__.py`](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/master/networkx/algorithms/__init__.py) does not import anything from `networkx.algorithms.approximations`.

Comment: The first time a package is imported, (e.g. `import networkx.algorithms`), the code in that package's `__init__.py` file is executed. Imported packages (and modules) are cached in `sys.modules`, so if a package is imported a second time, its value is simply looked up in `sys.modules` and the `__init__.py` file is not executed again.

Comment: Yes just checked the `__init__.py` in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/algorithms/__init__.py`, approximation package is not imported explicitly. Thanks! for the explanation.